# Check if array has same Latitude Longitude swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, mkmapview, mapkit

I have a class which has those data

```
class Events {
   var name: String!
   var latitude: Double!
   var longitude: Double!
}
```

And I fill it out with data from json.

So some Events have the same lat and lon but they are not on continuous, i mean its not that event3 is the same as event4 etc.

So I'm trying to show them on a map

Filling out this array

```
var events = [Events]()
```

And in this for loop i'm making the pins.

```
 for events in events {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = events.name

            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: events.latitude, longitude: events.longitude)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
```

How can I make a quick search before deploying the pins, to see if a pin has the same lat and lon with another pin, to add some digits just to show them both close?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does the ordering of the pins matter? If not, Swift's native `Set` will be perfect. Otherwise, you'll need to use a third party "ordered set" implementation

Comment: @Alexander nope it doesn't matter, could you write me an example of `Set` ?

Comment: `Set` is well documented. Please read up on it on the language guide, and come back to us if you run into difficulty using it.

Comment: Maybe this [stromid tutorial](https://blog.stormid.com/2015/10/mkmapview-pins-swift/) is helpful?

Comment: Will the lat/long values be EXACTLY the same? If not you might need some tolerance value, like a difference of < .00001 for both. And what do you want to do with Event objects with duplicate lat/long values? Keep the first one in array order? Randomize the values slightly? (Is that what you mean by "...add some digits just to show them both close?")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Set` to find unique instances.  In order to use `Set` your base element, `Events` in this case must be `Hashable` and by implication `Equatable`:

```
class Events : Hashable {
    var name: String!
    var latitude: Double!
    var longitude: Double!

    // implement Hashable        
    var hashValue: Int {
        return latitude.hashValue | longitude.hashValue
    }

    // Implement Equatable
    static func ==(lhs:Events, rhs:Events) -> Bool {
        return lhs.latitude == rhs.latitude && lhs.longitude == rhs.longitude
    }
}
```

Then your main loop is a direct extension of what you already have, note that this collapses all matches down to a single point and changes the name to indicate how many matches there are:

```
// Use a Set to filter out duplicates
for event in Set<Events>(events) {
    let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
    // Count number of occurrences of each item in the original array
    let count = events.filter { $0 == event }.count

    // Append (count) to the title if it's not 1
    annotation.title = count > 1 ? "\(event.name) (\(count))" : event.name

    // add to the map
}
```

If, instead, you want to move the points so that they don't stack up, then you want something like, where we build up the set of occupied locations as we go and mutate the points to move them a little.

```
func placeEvents(events:[Events], mapView:MKMapView) {
    var placed = Set<Events>()

    for event in events {
        if placed.contains(event) {
            // collision: mutate the location of event as needed,
        }

        // Add the mutated point to occupied points
        placed.formUnion([event])

        // Add the point to the map here
    }
}
```

If the values aren't expected to be exactly the same, but only within, eg., .0001 of each other, then you could use the following for `hashValue` and `==`

```
fileprivate let tolerance = 1.0 / 0.0001

private var tolerantLat : Long { return Long(tolerance * latitude) }
private var tolerantLon : Long { return Long(tolerance * longitude) }

var hashValue : Int {
    return tolerantLat.hashValue | tolerantLon.hashValue
}

static func ==(lhs:Events, rhs:Events) -> Bool {
    return lhs.tolerantLat == rhs.tolerantLat && lhs.tolerantLon == rhs.tolerantLon
}
```

Comment: Relevant to Duncan's comment, if the lat/long aren't expected to be EXACTLY the same, you'll have to play with the implementation of both `hashValue` and `==`  Remember that `hashValue` must return the same value for any pair for which `==` returns true.

Comment: Indeed the issue is for events on the exact place. And now i can change the lat and lon if count is > 1 right ?

Comment: Well, if you want to actually change the lat/long for subsequent matching points, the process is going to be substantially different.  But the implementation of `Hashable` and using a `Set` to detect duplicates would still work.

Comment: As i tried to add some extra values to the lat and lon it takes all the pins to that location. Could you help me approach this ?

Comment: Oh ok, i also setted up a counter - flag and at the second time that will be the same, then it will run the added values. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Actually no, my approach was stupid. If you can help me to change a bit the lat and lon if the place is the same, would be awesome :D